# AutoMapper Not Mapping... No Errors Thrown

Tags: c#, automapper

Here's that I have in my WPF application:

```
public static class MappingCreator
{
    public static void CreateMaps()
    {
        Mapper.CreateMap<SO.Services.Data.ServiceModel.Types.Customer, Customer>();
        Mapper.CreateMap<List<SO.Services.Data.ServiceModel.Types.CustomerSearchResult>, List<CustomerSearchResult>>();

        Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
    }
}
```

`CreateMaps()` is called once on application start.

DTO:

```
namespace SO.Services.Data.ServiceModel.Types
{
    [DataContract]
    public class CustomerSearchResult
    {
        [DataMember]
        public int CustomerId { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string AccountType { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string ShortName { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string LegacyName { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string LegacyContactName { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string City { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string StateAbbreviation { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string Country { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string PostalCode { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Model:

```
namespace SO.Models
{
    public class CustomerSearchResult : BindableBase
    {
        public int CustomerId { get; set; }
        public string AccountType { get; set; }
        public string ShortName { get; set; }
        public string LegacyName { get; set; }
        public string LegacyContactName { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        public string StateAbbreviation { get; set; }
        public string Country { get; set; }
        public string PostalCode { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Extension method:

```
public static class DtoMappingExtensions
{
    public static List<CustomerSearchResult> ToModels(this List<SO.Services.Data.ServiceModel.Types.CustomerSearchResult> customerSearchList)
    {
        return Mapper.Map<List<SO.Services.Data.ServiceModel.Types.CustomerSearchResult>, List<CustomerSearchResult>>(customerSearchList);
    }
}
```

I call a servicestack service which returns a `List<SO.Services.Data.ServiceModel.Types.CustomerSearchResult>` ... when I use the ToModels extension method against it, it returns a List with 0 records, even though the source list had 25k or so records.

I'm stumped.

Comment: I don't believe you need the List mapping. Just create the mappings for the individual entity objects (and do a .ReverseMap()) if you need them to go both ways. When yo do the Mapper.Map, you specify List<sourceobj>, list<destobj>(source) then.

Comment: Yep... that did it.... must have been an update to Automapper? A bunch of other similar questions said to do what I did. Thanks. Put what you said in an answer and I'll accept.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your CreateMaps() you would specify the object mappings, not the list mapping.

```
Mapper.CreateMap<SO.Services.Data.ServiceModel.Types.CustomerSearchResult, CustomerSearchResult>().ReverseMap();
```

And then in your ToModels() you do

```
Mapper.Map<List<CustomerSearchResult>, List<SO.Services.Data.ServiceModel.Types.CustomerSearchResult>>(customerSearchList);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is here in this line.

```
 Mapper.CreateMap<List<SO.Services.Data.ServiceModel.Types.CustomerSearchResult>, List<CustomerSearchResult>>();
```

this statement has no need because the AutoMapper will handle the Mapping of the list automatically when you Map the Classes.

I think you should replace the previous statement with this one

```
Mapper.CreateMap<SO.Services.Data.ServiceModel.Types.CustomerSearchResult, CustomerSearchResult>();
```